# list removal and merge in one line

Tags: python, list

In python, I want to **remove one item** from a list and then **merge** this list to a new one. Can I chain methods so this happens **in one line**?

For instance:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
# I want to remove 3 and add [10,11]
a.remove(3) #it doesn't return a, so I can't do this in one line
a += [10,11]
```

Comment: Is there a problem in doing two different operations on two separate lines?

Comment: Yes, I just want it to pass it to a function as an input parameter and it would be cool not to write a line just for such a simple operation :)

Comment: Can there be multiple `3`s (for example) in your list?

Comment: @RickyRobinson Where you say "cool", Python says "silly", because then you need two different `remove()` methods that have different return values, one that tells if the remove succeeded, and another that's "chainable". (Chainable APIs are neat for certain use cases but they do mean that you can't have any other meaningful return values except for the last step of the chain.)

Comment: Do you have repeated elements in "a"?

Comment: @millimoose: whenever you call two functions on a line, you have two return values. What's the problem here?

Comment: No repeated elements in `a`

Comment: @RickyRobinson I'm not sure what you mean by that. By two different return values I didn't mean that the expression would involve two method calls. What I meant is that `list` would have to have two methods like `removeAndReturnBoolean()` and `removeAndReturnSelf()` which fulfill the same purpose. Instead of having the current `remove()` method that has a return value that makes more sense, which is a `boolean` that tells you whether the element being removed was found in the list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a list comprehension and concatenation:

```
a = [i for i in a if i != 3] + [10, 11]
```

This would remove *multiple* copies of `3` in the list. If you only want to remove the *first* occurrence of `3` even if there are multiple copies, you need to stick to slicing:

```
a = a[:a.index(3)] + a[a.index(3) + 1:] + [10, 11]
```

but that incurs *two* searches for that index. Since you mention in comments that you have no repeats in your data, you should stick with the first option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this,

```
>>>print filter(lambda x: x is not 3, [1,2,3,4]) + [10,11]
[1, 2, 4, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the array without the position you want to remove and then concatenate the tail:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a = a[:2]+a[3:]+[10,11]
```

So you can remove one position in one line.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
new = (lambda b=iter(a): list(iter(b.next, 3)) + list(b) + [10, 11])()
# [1, 2, 4, 10, 11]
```

It's ugly - but removes the index lookup

Comment: @RickyRobinson You're the one that wants a one-liner - it's part and parcel I'm afraid ;)